# Creating Flask Real-time Dashboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am working on weather web app that will use data collected from Raspberry Pi sensor BME680, push it into database and push it further to the web dashboard. Here are questions i have:
1. Based on code I have bellow, is it smarter to push data to dashboard and into database in same time from the sensor, or get the data into database from the sensor, and then from database feed further into web-dashboard?
2. Based on the two code below, would it be possible to combine them into one flask application?

So far I have managed to create the code that will collect the data from sensor and push into database. I also have flask App that will extract data from database and push last value to the dashboard. I am trying to combine my data collection code with flask app and make it to push the data to web-dashboard every second.

Here is the code for gathering data from Sensor into Database

```
# Import Dependencies
import sqlite3
import time
import board
from busio import I2C
import adafruit_bme680
import datetime
# Create library object using our Bus I2C port
i2c = I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme680 = adafruit_bme680.Adafruit_BME680_I2C(i2c, debug=False)
# change this to match the location's pressure (hPa) at sea level
bme680.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25
# Define database name to which data will be stored
dbname = 'Sensors.db'
# Using while loop capture the data in variables and store it in database
while True:    
    # Create the now variable to capture the current moment
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    TEMPERATURE = round(bme680.temperature,1)
    GAS = round(bme680.gas,1)
    HUMIDITY = round(bme680.humidity,1)
    PRESSURE = round(bme680.pressure,1)
    ALTITUDE = round(bme680.altitude,1)
    TIME_STAMP =(now)

    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO BME_DATA (TIME_STAMP, TEMPERATURE, GAS, 
    HUMIDITY, PRESSURE, ALTITUDE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",(TIME_STAMP, 
    TEMPERATURE, GAS, HUMIDITY, PRESSURE, ALTITUDE))
    conn.commit()
    # Test by printing data from table BME_DATA
    #for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM BME_DATA"):   
        #print (row)
    conn.close()    
    time.sleep(1)
```

And here is the code for flask app that will take data from database:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import sqlite3
# Retrieve data from database
def getData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('../Sensors.db')
    curs=conn.cursor()
    for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM BME_DATA ORDER BY TIME_STAMP 
     DESC LIMIT 1"):
        Time = str(row[1])
        Temperature = row[2]
        Gas = row[3]
        Humidity = row[4]
        Pressure = row[5]
        Altitude = row[6]

    conn.close()
    return Time, Temperature, Gas, Humidity, Pressure, Altitude
# main route 
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    Time, Temperature, Gas, Humidity, Pressure, Altitude = getData()
    templateData ={'Time': Time,
        'Temperature': Temperature,
        'Gas': Gas,
        'Humidity': Humidity,
        'Pressure': Pressure,
        'Altitude': Altitude}
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=False)
```

So to run this i have to run both code in same time and what i get on the page is just last reading of the sensor values at the moment page is open. In order to get update i have to press the button and call the query in flask. So how do i combine these two to make one flask app that will data collection and also continuously push the data to dashboard?

I have research this and I think there has to be library socketio used to do this.